# Percentage Column in a Seeded Report of Purchase Requisition

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher

I'm creating a report using BI-Publisher but there's one thing that I can't find. Can someone help me where to find the column that contains the `percentage` in the `seeded report of purchase requisition` in oracle.
Thanks

Comment: `seeded report of purchase requisition` seems like it should be a feature of the data model. Are you using an Oracle supplied schema?

Comment: Yes. But when I check the seeded report in report and analytics. I find the report but I didn't find the data model.

Comment: Is this for E-Business Suite (EBS)?

Comment: Yes it is. @edhayes3

Comment: What do you want the percentage of? Can you share the XML extract that was generated from the concurrent request? What is the Concurrent Request name/code?